# Make some parts of image clickable

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to make certain logo's in this image clickable to urls.

Here is the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu0GQ.png

For example:

- I Want betfair and claim now to open www.betfair.com
- Than Bet365 Logo to open www.bet365.com
- Than Betvictor Logo to open betvictor.com
- and all bet text to open the site alongside them

How can I do that?

Comment: USE Dreamweaver, this editor has some tool for this

Comment: this is very easy i think in html using `<a>` tag

Comment: So use an HTML table with nested `<a>` elements (this is ***not*** a good use for an `<img />` element); that way the content is accessible to blind, partially-sighted readers too (and doesn't fall foul of any anti-discrimination legislation).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check out HTML Image map tags here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Fair enough, I will copy the relevant parts in

Answer (score 0):

Put image inside anchor tags and add `target="_blank"` to open links in other tab.

```
<a href="link" target="_blank"><image></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML Maps.You define different areas inside image via co-ordinates like,

```
<img src="PaTb5F2.png" width="145" height="126" alt="logo" usemap="#map">

<map name="map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="365" href="www.bet365.com">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="fair" href="www.betfair.com">
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This code, i got it from w3schools, it surly helps you

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
<area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm">
<area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm">
</map>
```

check this link : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_usemap.asp

Answer (score 0):

Check out HTML Area Map / HTML Image Map. There are many keywords for this, but they mostly get to the same html code.

You have a img tag:

```
<img src="IMAGE.png" width="X" height="Y" alt="ALT" **usemap="#map"**>
```

The `usemap` attribute points to the HTML map like this:

```
<map name="myMap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="10,10,50,100" href="www.your.link" alt="ALT">
  ... more <area> are possible
</map>
```

There are many tutorials that can help you with the options of the `<area> tags` just google it.

[HERE a generator i googled](http://www.image-maps.com/)